# Facebook plugin moderation comments not working for me

Tags: facebook, comments

I already have the following codes but the moderation is still not working. I'm the only admin/moderator.

```
<HEAD>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="MY_USER_ID"/>
</HEAD>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:comments href="MY_URL"></fb:comments>
```

Did I missed something?